# What is known of James Potter's parents?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Harry Potter saga it is said that Harry's only family left are the Dudleys. However there is nothing said about his family on the parent side (at least not that I can recall), so the question is what is known about the James Potter parents (Harry's grand parents)? Are they alive? wasn't there any uncle, cousin, something/someone Harry could count on on the father family side?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist No precisely what I asked, but on the accepted answer they also say what I wanted to know. Thanks

Comment: That's the definition of a duplicate question (on this site). If the answer to question A answers newly asked question B, B is a duplicate of A.

Comment: Duplicates aren't a bad thing, so I'd leave it. It's got a usefully searchable title which probably means the information is easier to find.